# How to fix 'Allowed memory size' when I try to retrieve a big column content

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to retrieve a row with a big content (67MB), but this doesn't finish when it run the query `findOrFail`, inmediately the log show the error `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71224881 bytes)`

Then before of the `findOrFail` add `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and it worked, but the problem with the memory limit is that could be crash the web server when the memory run out

Somebody knows how to avoid that error without use the memory limit?

This is my code

```php
// Doesn't work
$file = $query->findOrFail($id);
$file->download($request->filename);
```

```php
// It works
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$file = $query->findOrFail($id);
$file->download($request->filename);
```

This is the download method

```php
public function download($contentType = 'application/octet-stream') {
  header("Content-Type: $contentType");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$this->filename\"");
  echo $this->content;
}
```

Comment: You need to break down SQL queries into loops. It is not possible to load huge datasets into memory. But with loops you may process large data even with small memory. Trade off is, that you have to do multiple queries and think *smart* - e.g. load only ID column LIMIT, OFFSET and stream result into local file, then process it ... etc. 67 MB is definitely not a big content, think big data tens of million records in tens of gigabytes.

Comment: if you have only 128 MB, then 67MB is "big". Why is this blob served from the database and not from the filesystem? It is far easier to chunk a file than a blob-field..

Comment: @lubosdz if you see my code I am filtering just one ID, the column content has 67MB and if i could stream the result in a local file it would be good

Comment: If you can you should store binary contents directly in files, not in DB. This is more performant way.

Comment: @Daniel I can't store directly in files because the project was designed like that